# Why are my nested components not rendering?

Tags: vuejs2

Using the render function provided by `VueJS` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) the following works:

```
render(h, context) {
  
  let children = [];
  children.push(h("span", "test nested span"));
  return h(
    "span",
    children
  )      
}
// results in <span><span>test nested span</span></span>
```

But it does not work if I attempt to pass configuration data to the parent:

```
render(h, context) {
  
  let children = [];
  children.push(h("span", "test nested span"));
  return h(
    'span', {
      domProps: {
        innerHTML: "parent"
      },
      style: "...",
      class: "..."

    
    },
    children        
  )      
}
// results in <span>parent</span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

So I think what's happening here is the usage of `innerHTML` which is overriding the child elements because they are technically part of the `innerHTML`. But my goal is still the same. I want to be able to use `innerHTML` because it allows raw html and I also want to render the children after it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably passing a function `render` instead of the array `render`. It would be better if you changed `let render = []` to `let children = []`

Comment: Makes no difference. I even manually added child elements. If I pass arguments `{ domProps, etc. }` to the parent element children are ignored. I've updated my question to help clarify.

Comment: Ok, that being said I think it's like you said - domProps has higher priority thus children even though might be rendered they are later overriden by the innerHTML. Why do you need raw html in render function ?

Comment: I have a fairly advanced application where I'm allowing the end user to pass configurations `json` to populate components and due to the many accommodations the `dom` is getting messy with tags that I'd rather not be there (semantically speaking) and to help clean this up I want to render content in some places without a surrounding element, and need the ability to allow raw (trusted) content. So my question/example is a watered down simple example to help achieve a bigger goal all around. On top of that, it's just cool to figure things out.